# Galaxy S4 turn on camera flash cause onPictureTaken not get called

Tags: android, android-camera

I got a very annoyed bug on Galaxy S4 (other device works fine): when I turn on flash light, I can't take a picture because `onPictureTaken` isn't called. 
Here is my try:

```
  private void changeFlashMode(boolean isFlashOn) {
    if (mCamera != null) {          
        // assume I 've already checked support flash mode
        Camera.Parameters camParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        camParameters.setFlashMode(isFlashOn ? Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON : Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mCamera.setParameters(camParameters);
        startCameraPreview();        
    }
}
```

From debug, I can see it called to this line:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
```

and then nothing happened, `onPictureTaken` isn't called.

Could you please provide me an example?

Comment: Any solution for that bug? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Zhenya This problem is fixed but I can't remember what I did. All I remember is that I tried to start auto focus `camera.autoFocus(this);` after initializing and starting preview camera. You can check your code and try this.

Comment: I don't suppose you have since remembered what your solution was? I have the same issue, and with or without calling autoFocus I still can't get it to work with the flash.  @Zhenya did you work this one out?

Comment: Found a solution so in case it's still any use to you:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734522/custom-camera-picturecallback-does-not-run-if-flash-used-on-s4-devices/26802390#26802390)