# Custom Camera PictureCallback does not run if flash used on S4 devices

Tags: android, android-camera

I have written a basic custom camera which I recently changed to use the flash (where available) on the device.  Once I had made the change the code ran fine as before on my HTC One Mini 2, but no longer worked on my Galaxy S4.  After stepping through I found my jpeg callback is never reached on the S4, instead the raw callback is run but with a null byte[] supplied.

I found this similar question:
[S4 Flash Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929905/galaxy-s4-turn-on-camera-flash-cause-onpicturetaken-not-get-called#comment41912741_21929905)

Which seems to confirm there is an issue and solution on these devices but the solution has not been documented.

To re-iterate, the code works fine on the S4 so long as I don't turn on the flash with:

```
Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);//Or FLASH_MODE_ON
mCamera.setParameters(p);
```

Can anybody with experience on these devices provide the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error over the last week I have stumbled upon two possible solutions to this problem, the first of which doesn't make any sense to me at all:

1. Force the zoom to be greater than x1.  For some reason if I set the zoom to x1.2 etc. the camera works again as I would expect.
2. Ensure the aspect ratio of the selected picture size matches the native aspect ratio of the device.  The S4 has a resolution of 1920x1080 so any picture size that matches this 16:9 ratio works with the flash on.  This makes a bit more sense but why the flash makes the difference and why anything that isn't supported should be returned by getSupportedPictureSizes() I don't know (albeit they do seem to be without the flash.)

Currently I have chosen to use option 2 and am testing on my other devices.
Might also be worth mentioning that my next step on the S4 was to allow the user to turn the flash on/off/auto themselves but this required destroying and recreating the camera each time.

Comment: I have the same issue. I don't own a SG4 so is a bit tricky for me to test it. In my case I don't think is the aspect ratio as I am already matching it all the time. About the zoom solution, would it work if increased by 1? I mean, if the current zoom factor is 0 and is increased to 1 right before doing the picture, does it solve the problem? thank you

Comment: @Zhenya I don't know your app obviously but I would set the zoom when you set up the camera rather than at the last second otherwise the picture taken won't resemble the preview.  However, in my experience using setZoom(1) etc. should work.  Good luck.